# Converting Java to C# issue

Tags: c#, java

I am trying to convert a statsd Java client into a usable C# class. I used visual stuido 2005's convert feature on the java client and it has come up with a few errors no problem. I am not used to java and do not know how to convert a few of my errors into c#.
For instance on of the errors in a public bool class contains (String...keys) What does that mean in java? I am not familiar with '...'. Another in a for statement contains (String stat: stats) I would assume that means String stat || stats but I am not sure.

Comment: I think we need more detail. Can you give the full text of some of the errors? Perhaps even a bit of the code it is gagging on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Java:

```
public void foo(int x, String... keys)
```

is broadly equivalent to the C#

```
public void Foo(int x, params string[] keys)
```

In Java it's called a [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) parameter; in C# it's called a [parameter array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

In both cases they allow the caller to pass multiple arguments, and the compiler packages them up into an array... so this call:

```
Foo(5, "x", "y", "z");
```

is equivalent to

```
Foo(5, new string[] { "x", "y", "z" });
```

... but a bit simpler to read.

The `for (String stat : stats)` is the [*enhanced for loop*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (or just "for-each loop") in Java, and is broadly equivalent to a [`foreach` loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) in C#:

```
foreach (string stat in stats)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to look up each piece of syntax you don't understand individually and then post specifically which ones you need help with. Specifically, for the two instances you have mentioned here:

`String... keys` is how you use variable number of arguments in Java. (http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060106/VariableLengthArgumentLists.html)

`String stat: stats` is simply the foreach loop in Java (http://leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html)

This page can be a handy reference for you:
http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html

Answer (score 1):

It's been ages since i've used Java, but i believe

```
for (String stat: stats)
```

is Java syntax for a for-each statement. The C#-equivalent would be

```
foreach (String stat in stats)
```

I do not recognize 'String...keys'. Could you post some actual code?

Answer (score 0):

The `...` notation is a variable length parameter list identifier.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

It's basically equivalent to C#'s `params object[] objects` style of variable length argument lists.